# How to handle AJAX POST request in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a sort of twitter like button function in my app such that, when the button is clicked, it triggers an AJAX call and performs the action specified in the views. However, when i click the button, it does not perform action in views. The code reaches the 'like view' but does not execute anything after 'if request.POST:'. Please help.

> **Menu.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'like'%}" id="plt_{{menu.id}}" data-id="{{menu.id}}" method="post">
        {%csrf_token%}
   <input name="menu_id" type="hidden" value="{{ menu.id }}">
    <div class="like-button" id="btn_{{menu.id}}"></div>
</form>
```

```
<script>
     $('.like-button').on('click', function () {
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         id = id.replace('btn_','');

         $(this).toggleClass('animate').promise().done(function () {
            var link = $("#plt_"+id).attr('action')
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: link,
                    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                })
                });
    });

 </script>
```

> **Views.py**

```
def like(request):
    print('reached') //this prints
    if request.POST:
     menu = Menu.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('menu_id'))
     //execute code to like
     return HTTPResponse('')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to check

```
if request.is_ajax() and request.method== "POST":
```

`request.POST` is a dict .Empty here because body is empty in your request.

Empty dicts are treated **like** `False` by python like

```
if {}:
    print("Hello World")
```

Above won't print anything

But below works

```
if {"hi" : "there"}:
    print("Hello World")
```

And [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/) suggests this check is wrong `if request.POST:`

> It’s possible that a request can come in via POST with an empty POST
>   dictionary – if, say, a form is requested via the POST HTTP method but
>   does not include form data. Therefore, you shouldn’t use if
>   request.POST to check for use of the POST method; instead, use if
>   request.method == "POST" (see HttpRequest.method).

Comment: Glad it helped can you please accept as answer so that others can follow

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple, use `serialize()` of jquery. Serialize function will take all the values from the form, even `csrftokenmiddleware` which is hidden input type. So, doing so you will be able to handle `post` request successfully.  Use sthg like this:

```
<script>
     $('.like-button').on('click', function () {
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         id = id.replace('btn_','');

         $(this).toggleClass('animate').promise().done(function () {
            var link = $("#plt_"+id).attr('action');
            var data = $("#plt_"+id).serialize();   // It will serialize all form data
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: link,
                    data: data
                });
         });
    });

 </script>
```

In `views.py` do as you do for other request. [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: This helped alongside what @Yugandhar suggested. Thank you